Extracting web-publish exchange rates using google sheets IMPORTHTML function
I would like to extract specific exchange rates from two Thai banks:
https://www.bangkokbank.com/en/Personal/Other-Services/View-Rates/Foreign-Exchange-Rates#
https://exchangerate.krungthai.com/#/counterRate
I tried useing the IMPORTHTML() function in Google Sheets.  It work on the exchange rates published by other banks, but I'm faiing with these two.  Could somebody point me out in right direction?
Many thanks!
